# Django Rest Framework - "You do not have permission to perform this action" in tests

Tags: python, django, rest, testing, django-rest-framework

I have `Profile` model which is custom user model. When I try to change it (sending patch request) via postman, all is ok. But when I try to do it in tests in returns `"You do not have permission to perform this action" in response with ststus code 403.` 
Here is code:

```
# models.py
class Profile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=photo_upload, default = 'profile_pics/default_avatar.jpg',
            null=True, blank = True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank = True, null = True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    objects = ProfileManager()
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'first_name']

objects = ProfileManager()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('user', kwargs = {'pk': self.pk})

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user_name}' 


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.image:
        self.image = f"{os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'profile_pics')}/default_avatar.jpg"
    else:
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)`

# serializer class

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['email', 'user_name', 'first_name', 'surname', 'start_date', 'image', 'about', 'contacts']
        read_only_fields = ['start_date', 'user_name']

# views.py
class DetailUpdateDestroyUserAPI(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    Profile = apps.get_model('account', 'Profile')
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permisson_classes = [UserIsHimselfOrRO]
    lookup_field = 'user_name'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.Profile.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, user_name):
        user = get_object_or_404(self.Profile, user_name = user_name)
        profile = ProfileSerializer(user).data
        recents = collect_user_recents(user)
        data = {'profile': profile, 'recents': recents}
        return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def patch(self, request, user_name):
        data = ProfileSerializer(request.user, data=request.data, partial = True)
        if data.is_valid():
            data.save()
            return Response(ProfileSerializer(request.user).data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(data.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

# and finally, my test method
def test_update_user(self):
        user = self.Profile.objects.create(
            user_name = 'feyzu',
            email = 'donfeyzulla@gm.com',
            first_name = 'Feyzulla',
            password = make_password('testing123')
        )
        # user.save()
        self.assertEqual(self.Profile.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(user.user_name, 'feyzu')
        self.assertEqual(user.email, 'donfeyzulla@gm.com'),
        self.assertEqual(user.first_name, 'Feyzulla'),

        url = reverse('detail_user', kwargs={'user_name':'feyzu'})
        data = {'about': 'new about'}
        response = self.client.put(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)

        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f"Bearer {token.access_token}")
        response2 = self.client.patch(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response2.status_code, 200) # fails here: 403 != 200
```

Before I used permission class of `AllowAny` but it doesn't affect.
Here is DRF settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':[
            'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
            'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
            ],
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the web server has got rw rights on the media root?

Comment: I think yes, when server is running, it can take default image from media folder, and save into there if image has changed. But how can I check exactly? system: WSL

Comment: If you can read and write images then it is ok. Did you compare the http headers between postman and the failed request? Authentication token etc?

Comment: when i use postman, I just insert jwt token and body data, thats all. But in case of testing, something going wrong. Maybe, problem is related with csrf.

Comment: You need to return all cookies set by the server and also the correct headers.

Comment: Can you provide source or piece of code, obout this? I am not geek in request around world )

Comment: 'Piece of code' depends on the development environment you are using. Headers typically are inspected using the development tools of the browser. There are some basics you need to understand when starting web development.